# How to add JLabel to this?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I was wondering how to add a `JLabel` to the bottom right corner of this `JFrame`? I am also fairly new to coding so I will be taking this as a learning experience.:)

```
public class MainQuestions  {

    public static void main (String args[]){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        Object ARRAY[]={"French","English","Portugese","Spanish"};
        String answer=(String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What language  predominately spoken in Latin American countries?","World Geography Review", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, ARRAY, null);

        if(answer == null) {
            //System.exit(0);
        } else if(answer.equals("Spanish")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!", "World Geography Review", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null);
            //System.exit(0);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, wrong answer.", "World Geography Review", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null);
            //System.exit(0);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made an example for you, using `BorderLayout`

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test label");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
        //this set component orientation to the right!
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
        f.add(label,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

For more information about swing start reading this [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Ask me if you have problems :)

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
labelPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
JLabel bottomRtLabel = new JLabel("BOTTOM RIGHT LABEL");
labelPanel.add(bottomRtLabel);
frame.add(labelPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: it said cannot use this in a static context

Comment: sorry, you cannot use this keyword in this context then. If you want more info. HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664522/why-cant-we-use-this-keyword-in-a-static-method

Comment: I tried, no errors, but nothing showed? Sorry if i am being a complete noob on this.

Comment: try adding frame.setVisible(true); to the last line

Answer (score 0):

here is some pretty small Example which should help you to understand this:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(new JLabel("Label"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }
}
```