# Trying to make a static void available within all classes?

Tags: java, android

- Whoever downvotes - please explain, I am trying to learn, not an expert programmer and looking for assistance whilst trying to figure what is wrong - downvoting me is not helpful when someone is trying to learn.

In my android project, I have several .java files, one of them being a Global.java file.

What I would like to do, is create a method that I can call simply by using;

```
Global.showAdmob();
```

from any of the other java files.

The problem I have is, when I try to create the method inside the Global.java file, it mentions 'cannot use this in a static context'

Here is what I am trying to call from the other files;

```
    private static InterstitialAd interstitial;

        public static void displayInterstitial1() {
      if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
      }
    }

    public static void showAdmob() {

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);      

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            public void onAdLoaded(){
                 displayInterstitial1();
            }

            public void onAdClosed(){

            }

            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){


            }

  });
    }
```

Comment: remove private static  from declaring under method.

Comment: well that might be because `this` doesn´t really make sense in a `static` context. What are you trying to achive by passing `this` to the `InterstitialAd` constructor? what should `this` represent here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664522/why-cant-we-use-this-keyword-in-a-static-method

Comment: @Hypergater it made more sense with the last edit. This one looks confusing and like there is still missing something.

Comment: You are using keyword **this** in your static code? This is not allowed. But Looks like you Show us not the correct code

Comment: Changed edit, what I tried was to remove static and use it as a public void, but it would not work that way either

Answer (score 1):

might be you have to send **context** value in your

```
Global.showAdmob();
```

like

```
Global.showAdmob(MainActivity.this);
```

because **Global** is not either Activity or fragment class and in your **Global** you have to make change as

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(context);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you, so would I need to also declare context anywhere? Like at the top of the file like;

`static context context;`

?

Comment: no need to declare, you are getting it as parameter of your method.

Comment: If I call `Global.showAdmob(MainActivity.this);` I receive an error "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: is this your **MainActivity** inside which you are calling this method?

Comment: I am calling it in GameOverLayer.java

Comment: is it your Activity or Fragment class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123693/discussion-between-hypergater-and-rahul-sharma).