# Scope of statics and key word "this" in java

Tags: java, static, this

I have a question about this fragment of code :

```
public class Inner {

static int a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a = 0;
    }

    public static void g() {
        this.a = 0;
    }
}
```

`

Why we can't use "this.a" in static method, but we can use "a" without "this"?

Photo of compilation error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q6y3ldsf37p0h3/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202017-05-27%2017.28.34.png?dl=0

Comment: read this [Why can't we use 'this' keyword in a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664522/why-cant-we-use-this-keyword-in-a-static-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **this** points to an instance of the class, in the **static** method you don't have an instance.

> The **this** keyword refers to the current instance of the class. Static member functions do not have a **this** pointer

You'll notice the definition of a static member is

> Use the **static** modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object

Which is why **this** has nothing to point to.