# how to create a Request Queue in a static function

Tags: java, request-queueing

```java
public static List<GasType> getGasTypeList() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
}
```

this can not be referenced from a static context

I tried everything I know but still no result.

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword. You cannot access `this` when your function is static.

Comment: Note that JavaScript and Java aren't related, so have removed the tag for the former.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we use 'this' keyword in a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664522/why-cant-we-use-this-keyword-in-a-static-method)